# Which discussion board is good for homework questions?

Tags: big-list, education, online-resources

I'm a CompSci university student and i want some help for my math questions.
Therefore i am looking for a good discussion board for **math homework questions**.
I don't know any (good), because I come from an *non-native-english-speaking* country.

any ideas ?

> **note** : I know that I could post my questions here, but:
>   1. this is not a discussion board, where I can discuss **about** my
>   question
>   2. I won't annoy the experts with "simple" algebra question :)

Comment: This site is, almost by definition, for not-necessarily-expert questions, and homework does not differ, in principle, from any other category of material here. If there are special features to a homework question (you want only hints, or you want some calculation verified, or an answer that uses only elementary material, or only the theory in a specific textbook, etc) then mentioning this in the question will lead to more "adapted" answers.  Some users are more likely to answer homework if the question includes partial progress or is tagged as [homework], but such extra data are voluntary.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at this:
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Here are some:

- [Math Help Forum](https://mathhelpforum.com/)
- [Dr. Math (now discontinued)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://en.allexperts.com/c/science/8.htm