# Useful mathematical fora

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I want to ask about various mathematical fora and discussion boards available online. I think it might be useful to have such a list here at Math.SE.

If I may suggest, it could be useful to keep one long list with basic information as a community wiki, and if you want add some additional information on some of them, a separate answer might be the best way. (E.g. information like: "this forum is particularly suitable for questions about contest math" or "this forum is frequented by specialists in computer algebra, most discussions are about CAS software such as GAP", etc.)

In particular, if you deem some of other fora more suitable for some kind of questions than math.SE, this would probably be an interesting information for users of this site.

A related question: [Which discussion board is good for homework questions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/which-discussion-board-is-good-for-homework-questions)

Comment: My instinct would suggest that this kind of a list would be better placed in Meta, but let's see how others feel about that. Before I found this place, I was active in the math section of http://fora.xkcd.com. It isn't nearly as useful or active as this place, and also it is a tad too "chatty". But (being moderated) better than, say, the troll-infested usenet group sci.math.

Comment: @Jyrki I've added that forum to the list. Since you are familiar with the forum, you could perhaps check, whether the information I've given there is correct.

Comment: Somewhat related question on MathOverflow meta: [Any other site besides mathoverflow and mathematics stackexchange?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1181)

Answer (score 49):

**English language**

- Of course, there is [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), many users of this site are active there too. google: [mathoverflow site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=mathoverflow+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)
- [sci.math](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/), Usenet group, google: ["sci.math" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sci.math%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [AoPS - Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/), phpBB, supports TeX using [LatexRender](http://www.mayer.dial.pipex.com/tex.htm), google: [artofproblemsolving site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=artofproblemsolving+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [MHF - mathhelpforum](https://mathhelpforum.com/), supports TeX, google: [mathhelpforum site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=mathhelpforum+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [mymathforum](http://www.mymathforum.com/), phpBB, suports TeX, google: [mymathforum site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=mymathforum+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Physics Forums - Sub-forum Mathematics](http://www.physicsforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=4), google: [physicsforums site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=physicsforums+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)
- [S.O.S. Mathematics CyberBoard](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/), phpBB, supports TeX using [LatexRender](http://www.mayer.dial.pipex.com/tex.htm),
  google: [sosmath site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=sosmath+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Topology Q+A Board](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa), google: ["yorku.ca" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22yorku.ca%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Free Math Help](http://www.freemathhelp.com/forum/forum.php), google: ["freemathhelp.com" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22freemathhelp.com%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Math Help Boards](https://mathhelpboards.com/), google: ["mathhelpboards.com" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22mathhelpboards.com%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Tetration forum(about)](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum-about.html)
  and [Forum itself](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum) (moderated, all levels,phpBB,TeX), google: [tetrationforum site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=tetrationforum+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- <s>[Mathematics subforum of xkcd](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewforum.php?f=17); phpBB; supports LaTeX using [jsMath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JsMath) - but they prefer avoiding it where possible, so that the site is not slowed down, see [here](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=73302); google: ["fora.xkcd.com" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22fora.xkcd.com%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)</s> This forum no longer exists.
- [Abstract and Linear Algebra](http://www.math.miami.edu/forum/algebra/). , Google: ["math.miami.edu/forum" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22math.miami.edu/forum%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Purplemath](http://www.purplemath.com/learning/index.php), phpBB, supports LaTeX;
  Google: ["purplemath.com" site:stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22purplemath.com%22+site%3Astackexchange.com)
- [Wikipedia Reference desk Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Mathematics)
- [Integrals and Series](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/integralsandseries/), users communicate in TeX while the interface does NOT render.

**German language**

- [de.sci.mathematik](http://groups.google.com/group/de.sci.mathematik/), Usenet group
- [Matroids Matheplanet](https://matheplanet.com/), supports LaTeX

**Czech language**

- [Matematické Fórum](http://forum.matematika.cz/) at matematika.cz (formerly matweb.cz); supports TeX

**Italian language**

- [Matematicamente.it/forum](http://www.matematicamente.it/forum), phpBB, supports LaTeX using MathJax; Google: [matematicamente.it/forum site:stackexchange.com](https://www.google.it/search?q=matematicamente.it/forum+site:stackexchange.com).
  The forum also has an English language section (called *English Corner*).

**Russian language**

- [dxdy](https://dxdy.ru/), phpBB, supports LaTeX.

Comment: I've included links to google searches in some places; I think it might be interesting to see, whether these fora are often mentioned in math.SE posts.

Comment: I removed "Integrals and Series".  It was great for a while, but dead since 2017.

Comment: fora.xkcd.com has been offline since 2019 data breach.

Comment: @AlphaDelta I have edited the post. The answer is CW, feel free to add more details if you wish to.

Comment: Control+F does not find it; how about [codidact](https://codidact.com/)?