# Websites that promote co-operation and social networking among mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, big-list, online-resources, experimental-mathematics

Are there some websites that could be defined as *social networks for mathematicians and scientists*? What I have in mind is something similar to Academia.edu or ResearchGate, but more specific towards mathematics and less formal ("Facebook-type", *so to say*): a place for discussing and sharing ideas without the "constraints" (so to say) of Q&A or forum formats.

Also, in case that such places do exist, is there any evidence that this forms of cooperation have produced some results in terms of co-authored published papers, just like many cooperations born on M.SE and MathOverflow have?

Comment: Expecting down and close votes from people who didn't read the question on its entirety.

Comment: @Dal Do you mean websites like academia.edu and researchgate.net? They are primarily social networks than QA websites, although they include QA as well. (SE does not have networking at all, in that you cannot "friend" or "follow" people, or even message them in private, as far as I understand).

Comment: @GitGud: I have read it in its entirety and I still believe it is not on topic.

Comment: I read the entire question. I downvote it because I think we are no facebook. We are a community. We are a Q&A site. I don't know about others. I come here to learn math, not to socialize.

Comment: @tomasz Honestly, how is my question more off-topic than http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora?

Comment: @scaaahu As I wrote:  it could be true in *some sense* [...] ***but surely the philosophy behind the Stack Exchange network is (as far as I understand) radically different***.

Comment: @scaaahu: But OP is not suggesting anything of the sort. He's asking about other sites that *are* like that. Besides, you can't deny the fact that there is some socializing here.

Comment: @tomasz I disagree, but I respect your opinion. My comment was addressed to people who would end up not reading the entire question and down vote it anyway.

Comment: @scaaahu Your comment suggests you didn't read the question. I find it perfectly on-topic to ask about mathematical communities, on-line or otherwise.

Comment: @Dal: soft questions can sometimes be on the verge of being off-topic. Sometimes nominally off-topic posts may nonetheless we worth preserving. I'm not saying that none of existing posts cross the line, I'm just saying that IMO yours does. I think the one you linked is more on-topic in that it is about discussing mathematics in particular, rather than social networking.

Comment: @Dal: That said, I would be interested in learning if such a thing exists (though I doubt it does), so I wouldn't be terribly disappointed if the vote failed or was overturned. Still, it seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @GitGud Again, I read the entire question. This question has nothing to do with Math.SE at all. The downvote is for the mismatch between the first paragraph and the second one.

Comment: @tomasz Really, I didn't mean discussing social networking, but *cooperation and networking among mathematicians*. Anyway, what can I do to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: @Dal: I think it just does not belong here. I'm not sure where it does, though I suspect a proper rewording *might* be on-topic on meta. You might also try asking around on chat, I haven't really partcipated in it, but from what I've seen, it does have quite the social networking flavour.

Comment: @tomasz I see. Thank you for sharing your opinion. By the way, I've reworded the question. Does it sound somewhat better now?

Comment: @Dal: Yeah, I think it's better. Certainly less inflammatory for people who *really* don't like to be compared to Facebook, as witnessed by some comments here. ;)

Comment: @Dal: I think http://polymathprojects.org/ is definitely one that should be listed in the answer - but I am not its user, so I'd prefer an answer to be written by someone who has more encounters with polymath. You may be also interested in two preprints by Ursula Martin and Alison Pease: [What does mathoverflow tell us about the production of mathematics?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0904) and [Mathematical practice, crowdsourcing, and social machines](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0900)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of such websites is http://polymathprojects.org/. See, for example, a [January 2015 blogpost by Peter Cameron](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/polymath/) about this project.

I suggest also to look at two preprints by [Ursula Martin](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ursula.martin/) and Alison Pease:

- [What does mathoverflow tell us about the production of mathematics?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0904)
- [Mathematical practice, crowdsourcing, and social machines](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0900)

where one could find some further particulars relevant to the question, and also at the project ["The Social Machine of Mathematics"](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/MSM/).

Update: came across an article from the [Newsletter of the European Mathematical Society](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/newsletter/pdf/2014-12-94.pdf) called *The “Bounded Gaps between Primes” Polymath Project* (the author is stated as *D. H. J. Polymath*).